# Using reflection to build UI controls

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following interface declared:

```
   public interface IDemoInterface
   {
      bool DemoBooleanProperty { get; set; }
      string DemoStringProperty { get; set; }
      IContainer RestrictiveContent { get; set; }
   }
```

and I implemented for this a method that uses reflection to build some UI controls based on the property type

```
      public void BuildUiControls<T>(T instance, bool groupData = false)
      {
         foreach (var propertyInfo in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
         {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            {
               ...
            }

            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
              ...
            }
            
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
               ...
            }

            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(IContainer))
            {
               BuildUiControls(???, true);
            }
         }

      }
```

I managed to build the controls for the first ifs but now I want to use this function recursively to build the controls the same way but now for the IContainer interface which is a member of the initial interface and it seems that **I cannot figure it out what should I pass to the BuildUIControls method in order to access the properties from this interface**:

```
   public interface IContainer
   {
      TestEnum MandatoryEnum { get; set; }

      bool ReadOnly1Prop { get; set; }

      bool ReadOnly2Prop { get; set; }
   }
```

On the first call of this method I pass the data like this

```
         _demoInterface = new DemoInterfaceImplementation
         {
            DemoBooleanProperty2 = true,
            DemoStringProperty = "testString",
            RestrictiveContent = new ContainerInterfaceImplementation
            {
               MandatoryEnum = TestEnum.One, ReadOnly1Prop = true, ReadOnly2Prop = true
            }
         };
         vm.BuildUiControls(_demoInterface);
```

where the _demoInterface is declared as IDemoInterface.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the point of using any interfaces if you are going to ignore them and just use reflection?

Comment: @Andy All I can use in the final project is the interfaces, that's all I can access. What I posted is just a sample for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code in question:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(IContainer))
{
   BuildUiControls(???, true);
}
```

What you need to do is get the value of that property, then you can recursively call your method with the value. For example:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(IContainer))
{
    var containerValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(instance) as IContainer;
    BuildUiControls(containerValue);
}
```